# Как сделать проверку по времени?

Tags: php

Нужно сделать проверку по времени, что бы можно было заходить в админку в указное время. Например можно было заходить с 09 : 00 : 00 и по 18 : 30 : 00, `date("H:i:s");` отдает время сервера, но как сделать проверку не могу сообразить?

Comment: с 9 до 18 по времени сервера или клиента?

Comment: По времени сервера.

Comment: Добавил ответ, только что проверил - рабочий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dateStart = date('09:00:00');
$dateEnd = date('18:00:00');
$currentDate = date("H:i:s");
if($currentDate >= $dateStart && $currentDate <= $dateEnd) {
    //время корректное, работаем
} else {
    //время не попало в интервал, выход
}
```

Comment: Все работает спасибо.

Comment: @СашаБоричевский а почему так `$dateStart = date('09:00:00');` а не так `$dateStart ='09:00:00';` ?

Comment: @Эдуард честно - просто привычка, не более) Плюс подобная запись приведет к единому формату и исключит возможные ошибки

Comment: @СашаБоричевский какой формат? Какие ещё ошибки? Что за ересь вы несёте? Исправьте лучше ваш ответ, чтоб не плодить быдлокод.